# Additivization of functors in an abelian monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories, functors

Crossposted on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362283/additivization-of-functors-in-an-abelian-monoidal-category-crosspost-from-mse).

---

I'm having trouble with the proof of Lemma 2.9 in "[Cohomology of Monoids in Monoidal Categories](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.25.3891&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" by Baues, Jibladze, and Tonks, and I was wondering if someone could clarify a detail. I'll try to summarize the context of the lemma.

### Context

Let $(\Bbb A,\circ,I)$ be an abelian monoidal category where $\circ$ is left distributive, i.e. the natural transformation
$$(X_1\circ Y)\oplus(X_2\circ Y)\rightarrow (X_1\oplus X_2)\circ Y$$
is an isomorphism. For example, $\Bbb A$ could be the category of linear operads (this is a motivating example of the article). Given an endofunctor $F$ of $\Bbb A$, we define its *cross-effect*
$$F(A|B):=\ker(F(A\oplus B)\rightarrow F(A)\oplus F(B)).$$
The *additivization* of $F$ is then the functor $F^\text{add}$ defined by
$$F^\text{add}(A):=\text{coker}\left(F(A|A)\rightarrow F(A\oplus A)\xrightarrow{F(+)}F(A)\right).$$
The idea is that $F^\text{add}$ is the additive part of $F$.

Let $(M,\mu,\eta)$ be an internal monoid in $\Bbb A$, and let $L_0$ be the endofunctor $L_0:A\mapsto M\circ(M\oplus A)$. Let $L:=L_0^\text{add}$ be the additivization of $L_0$. (In the case of operads, represented as planar trees, I see $L(A)$ as the space of trees whose nodes are all labeled by elements of $M$ except for one leaf, which is labeled by an element of $A$.)

Suppose now that $\Bbb A$ is *right compatible with cokernels*, i.e. that

> for each $A\in\Bbb A$, the additive functor $A\circ-:\Bbb A\rightarrow\Bbb A$ given by $B\mapsto A\circ B$ preserves cokernels.

Then, in the proof of Lemma 2.9, the authors claim the following:

> By the assumption that $\Bbb A$ is right compatible with cokernels it follows that $L(L(X))$ is the additivisation of $L_0(L_0(X))$ in $X$ [...].

### Remarks

If anyone could **provide an explanation of the last claim**, I would be very grateful. However, my inability to understand how to show this might be related to two other issues I have:

1) Elsewhere in the literature, cross-effects are only defined when $F$ is *reduced*, i.e. $F(0)=0$ (e.g. [here](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~vespa/Cours-Tokyo-2019.pdf), section 2). But we can always reduce a functor by taking the cokernel of $F(0)\rightarrow F(X)$, so I don't think it's much of a problem.

2) In the first quote, the authors state that $A\circ -$ is additive, which is quite the opposite of the initial hypothesis that $\circ$ be *left* distributive, and not necessarily *right* distributive. How to resolve this apparent conflict?

Comment: Is $F^\text{add}$ really additive? If $F(A \oplus B) \to F(A) \oplus F(B)$ is monic for all objects $A$ and $B$, then $F^\text{add}$ would just be $F$, and the map would also need to be epic for it to be an isomorphism.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Do you have an example in mind where $F(A\oplus B)\rightarrow F(A)\oplus F(B)$ is monic for all objects $A$ and $B$, but is not epic for some $A$ and $B$? I'm not familiar enough with abelian category theory to come up with one. My (admittedly untrustworthy) intuition says that $F(A\oplus B)\rightarrow F(A)$ should be epic...

Comment: EDIT: Actually, you are absolutely right. $F:A\mapsto A\oplus C$ for some object $C$ makes the morphisms monic, but not epic. This was actually a problem that I encountered, and is why I asked if we needed to require $F$ to be reduced. In the case where $F$ is reduced, I feel like it should be true at least for categories of vector spaces.

Comment: If $F$ preserves zero, then the product comparison map $F(A \oplus B) \to F(A) \oplus F(B)$  is a split epimorphism (with the coproduct comparison map $F(A) \oplus F(B) \to F(A \oplus B)$ as a section), so if the product comparison map is monic, it must in fact be an isomorphism.